# Vaadin tree onclick expand

Tags: vaadin

I am new to Vaadin and I want to know how can I expand tree node on click? More precisely I want the tree to expand when I click on parent node not expand button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite easy to create a tree in Vaadin: https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/components.tree.html

Comment: I know how to create a tree I want the tree node to expand when I click on it.

Comment: I guess you mean clicking on the label, because you can expand it by clicking on the little arrow next to it.
You will need a Listener to do that:
http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler-for-vaadin6#TreeMouseEvents
The tree has an expandItem(String itemId) method, which should be called after the left-click event.

Comment: Yes that exactly what I want. I'll try your suggessiton

Answer (score 1):

For example if you want to expand all nodes in vaadin.ui.Tree:

```
// --- Expand all nodes
for (Iterator<?> it = tree.rootItemIds().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    tree.expandItemsRecursively(it.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This working for me:

```
@Override
        public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent itemClickEvent) {
            final String column = itemClickEvent.getPropertyId().toString();
            final String item = (String) itemClickEvent.getItemId();
            if (column.equals(something)) {
                Boolean collapsed = functieTree.isCollapsed(item);
                LOGGER.debug("COLLAPSED: " + collapsed);
                tableTree.setCollapsed(item, !collapsed);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tree.addItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent event) {
        menu.expandItem(event.getItemId());
    }
});
```

this works to me